# (Python) Is there a way to break up a script so that the output can be used as the input for another UDF in the same script?

Tags: python

Horrible title... I'm trying my best to explain what I'm trying to do...

Essentially, I have this script with many user-defined functions. It takes data from various csv files and long story short it spits out a single csv file to some output folder. That's all fine, however I need to use that output file to generate ANOTHER output, basically doing a transformation on the original output file. Now, I can do this easily enough by simply writing another package... but I want this done all in the original script. If I just copy/past the code from the second package, the original script simply won't read it... because it doesn't recognize the csv path + filename from the output (I'm assuming because Python is running everything concurrently and hence that original output file hasn't actually been written by the time Python gets to the next part of the code).

So, I have something like:

```
    def run_batch(x,y,z):
        #bunch of code setting up/collecting configuration data and setting up a dict for settings

    def construct(a,b,c):
        #code detailing the calcs

    return scenarios

    #setup the output file paths

    configuration_path = "some folder a"

    data_path = "some folder b"

    output_path = "some folder c"

    run_batch
```

Now. I want to manipulate the output that is being sent to the output_path location, and then have Python create another file in the same output path. I've written another package that's something like:

```
def convert_data(csv_path,name1,name2):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path + '\\' + name1)
    z = some UDF that transforms the original output
    outfile = open(csv_path + '\\' + name2)
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(z).T
    df_2.to_csv(outfile)
    outfile.close()

csv_path = "location of the output folder (output_path)"
name1 = "name of the csv file from the original output"
name2 = "name of the new csv file from this script"
```

This does exactly what I want. But I do not want these to be run in two separate .py files; I want to consolidate them into a single .py file

Is this possible?

Comment: When you say a "package" do you mean a single file script? Also, why would you assume that Python is running everything concurrently?

Comment: Yes, as they are now, these are two separate .py files. I would like to combine them into one. And maybe "concurrently" isn't the right term... but Python just doesn't seem to read the output file in the folder when I have both .py files combined into one. The second .py file just won't run if I add it to the first .py file (as if there was no csv file in the output). I've tried things like adding a time.sleep after the first portion hoping the output file would be written in the folder before the second part kicked in... but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in the same script. For example, using a context manager:

```
def convert_data(csv_path, name_1, name_2):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path + '\\' + name1)
    z = some UDF that transforms the original output
    with open(csv_path + '\\' + name2) as outfile:
        df_2 = pd.DataFrame(z).T
        df_2.to_csv(outfile)
```